# Is there a way to tell the number of solutions of these systems other than using Gauss-Jordan elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a couple of problems in my book (regarding expressing a vector as a linear combination of other vectors) and am trying to understand the steps my book uses to solve them. Here's the part I'm confused on in both problems:

---

**Problem 1:**

$2c_{1} + 5c_{2} = -1$

$-c_{1} = -2$

$3c_{1} + 4c_{2} = 2$

The solution of this system is $c_{1}=2, c_{2} = -1$

---

**Problem 2:**

$2c_{1}+ 5c_{2} = 1$

$-c_{1} = 1$

$3c_{1} + 4c_{2} = -1$

This system has no solution

I just would like to know how they figured out the number of solutions; is there a way to tell just by looking at the systems or did they omit a bunch of other assumed steps?

Does the book want us to solve using Gauss-Jordan elimination (it did in a similar example earlier in the book) -- or is there an easier way? It seems like I could just solve for $c_{1}$ and plug in  -- for example in the second system, plugging $c_{1}$ into the other equations would give two different values for $c_{2}$, by which I could draw the conclusion that there is no solution -- but would this be an accurate method?

Is that even the method I should be using in a linear algebra course (maybe I should stick to matrices)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to figure out what is happening in the Problem 2 you should calculate the Augmented Matrix Rank and compare the rank with coefficient Matrix Rank, if they are equal then the system is solvable.

$Rank(A\star)$ = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & 1\\
3 & 4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

Where the rank is $3$. Since the coefficient Matrix has rank $2$ then it doesn't have a solution. If you stick to Problem 1, then you will see that both matrices (coefficient and augmented) have the same rank, therefore first problem has a solution.

The naive approach would be plugging the value of $c_{1}$ in 1st equation and 2nd equation, as you say, will give you two different values for $c_{2}$.

Comment: We haven't gotten to rank yet in my course but at least this cleared up that I probably shouldn't just plug in the value of c1. I thought about it more and I'm guessing we are supposed to use Gaussian elimination